# Remoting , Messaging and Data Management in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

Can anyone explain me the difference of all and also an another question does Zend AMF support all these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though my answer may not be complete, it'll give you some hints.

**Flash Remoting** is a way of doing RPC using AMF protocol. Basicly you implement some server-side services with some methods, call them from your flex application and receive the result (using [RemoteObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html?mx/rpc/remoting/RemoteObject.html&mx/rpc/remoting/class-list.html)). Zend AMF definitely supports this.

**The Message Service** provides a complete publish/subscribe infrastructure allowing Flex clients and the server to exchange messages in real time. (from Wikipedia [article on BlazeDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlazeDS)). I believe, it's mostly a Java thing, and is used for distributing messages across several clients. [Making a chat](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Creating+a+BlazeDS+messaging+application+in+Flex+Builder) is a good example of it's usage.

**Data management** is a set of features provided by LCDS (Live Cycle Data Services), which eases the development of CRUD. More info you can find in asnwers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77198/what-does-blazeds-livecycle-data-services-do-that-something-like-pyamf-or-rubyam).

It's likely Zend AMF doesn't support the latter two features, though I'm not sure.