# Using Flex/Air with Java EE

Tags: java, apache-flex, air, websphere

I work on a large financial system which is hosted on WebSphere and currently has an applet front end.

I am just playing around with Flex for the first time and I am really impressed with the quality of the framework. I am interested to see if there is anyway I can integrate Flex into my Java EE application in a simple type safe fashion.

As a complete newbie I have no idea how to go about doing this;

- What would be the easiest way to invoke a Java method from the UI whilst hosted within a container (please dont say javascript!!)
- How would you go about pushing updates to the UI

Thanks in advance.

Karl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/)

Generally you call some method on the server side and get some data back. 
After receiving the data, you update your UI accordingly.
It's actually all rather easy, flex was designed to display and edit data easily.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to push data from the server side rather than poll for new data?

Comment: Yes, it's possible with messaging service of BlazeDS. Look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964440/remoting-messaging-and-data-management-in-flex